# Multi-device Bcrypt library for delphi XE8

Tags: android, delphi, bcrypt, delphi-xe8

I was able to find two Bcrypt libraries that can be compiled for windows but I am struggling to compile them for Android in Delphi XE8.

The first one is https://github.com/chinshou/bcrypt-for-delphi which doesn't require any modifications to be compiled for Windows.

For the second one https://github.com/PonyPC/BCrypt-for-delphi-lazarus-fpc I had to make some minor adjustments in the checkPassword function to get the same result since it was FreePascal specific:

```
function checkPassword(const Str: string; const Hash: ansistring): boolean;
var
  RegexObj: TRegEx;
  match   : TMatch;
  Salt    : String;
begin
  RegexObj := TRegEx.Create('^\$2a\$10\$([\./0-9A-Za-z]{22})',[roIgnoreCase]);
  match := RegexObj.Match(Hash);
  if match.Success then
  begin
    Salt := Copy(match.Value,8,22);
    Result := HashPassword(Str, Salt) = Hash;
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

After changing the platform from Win to Android the first one shows a lot of errors since it depends on ComObj, Windows and ActiveX. The second one after replacing RegExpr with RegularExpressions and Types shows only conflicts that results from [changes in the String variable](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Unicode_in_RAD_Studio). The code uses AnsiString, AnsiChar which I cannot just replace with String and Char since it affects the hashing function.

What am I missing? what other modifications should I do to replace the obsolete AnsiString and AnsiChar declarations, allowing the code to be compiled for Android?

Comment: If it requires ActiveX, it ***will not*** work for Android or any other platform. ActiveX is strictly Windows only. Same with the other one, you can't expect to simply replace `AnsiChar` with `String` and expect it to even work in Windows. You're better off finding a different library, such as LockBox 10.

Comment: LockBox 10 is multi-platform, and supports Blowfish: https://github.com/TurboPack/LockBox

Comment: All of the libraries that I mentioned are windows only not only ActiveX however some parts of the code can be replaced with FMX functions which is what I tried to achieve with the second, more compatible library. I never expected this code to work by simply replacing the string declarations, where did you get that idea? As for the LockBox I will give it a shot, it looks very promising.

Comment: Your question(s) in the last paragraph ("What am I missing?" and "What other modifications...") seem to indicate you really want to re-use the second library you found, that's where I got that idea. It was designed for Windows, and has very Windows specific stuff.

Comment: This whole question is about reusing those libraries but still I never expected it to be as simple as replacing AnsiString with String which is what I wrote in the paragraph before those two questions. We obviously misunderstood each other.

Comment: I understand, that's why it was in the form of a comment and not an answer.  I was simply reiterating and clarifying what you said. Different platforms require things to work differently.

Comment: I was unable to successfully use the LockBox library although I managed to alter the Bcrypt code which now works perfectly on Android (answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String declaration problem with the second library was caused by the move command in the HashPassword function

```
Move(password[1], key[0], Length(password));
```

since the size of the password variable changed after replacing the declaration from AnsiString to String. Replacing this with a simple for loop and Ord function fixes the problem although there is probably a more elegant way of doing it.

```
function HashPassword(const Str: string; const salt: string): string;
var
  password: String ;
  key, saltBytes, Hash: TBytes;
  i: Integer;
begin
  password := AnsiToUtf8(str);

  SetLength(key, Length(password) + 1);
  for i := 0 to length(password)-1 do
    key[i]:=ord(password[i+1]);

  key[high(key)] := 0;
  saltBytes := BsdBase64Decode(salt);
  Hash := CryptRaw(key, saltBytes);
  Result := FormatPasswordHashForBsd(saltBytes, Hash);
end;
```

To summarize, the conversion of the [second library](https://github.com/PonyPC/BCrypt-for-delphi-lazarus-fpc) to an Android compatible code requires the following changes:

- modifying the regular expression code in the checkPassword function
  according to the code posted in the question
- altering the uses section by replacing "RegExpr" with "RegularExpressions, Types"
- replacing all declarations from AnsiString to String and AnsiChar to Char
- modifying the HashPassword function as shown above

Comment: Doesn't look right to me. string is UTF-16 encoded. You want a byte array. Text and binary are not the same thing.

Comment: please, can you put your entyre code with all the modifications?